# PostgreSQL and schedule Windows 2012 R2 Schedule

Tags: windows, powershell, psql

I have a question, last saturday when I was migrate DC from Windows 2003 to 2012R2, everything was migrate ok, but I can't run a ps script on Windows 2012R2. I change some parameter, mail adress etc.

```
 param([String]$EmailTo = "user@domain.com")


psql.exe -h 10.1.1.20 -p 5432 -w -H -f C:\Scripts\errors_o_htm_V3.sql' -o 'C:\Scripts\errors.html -U script database

$file = "C:\Scripts\errors.html"
$old = Get-Content $file

Add-Content -Path $file -Value $old 

$EmailFrom = "sender@domain.com"
$Subject = "Reports"


$SMTPServer = "smtp.serwer.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","password");




$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage


$msg.From = $EmailFrom
$msg.To.Add($EmailTo)
     $msg.To.Add("user@domain.com")

$msg.Subject = $Subject 
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $True
$msg.Body = $old
$msg.BodyEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("UTF-8")


$SMTPClient.Send($msg)
```

When I run script manualy, he generate error file and send it, but when I want to set it in scheduler - he send an empty mail, something wrong with psql.exe -h ......
I add psql path to Environment Variables.

In scheduler i set:
Program/Script powershell.exe or full path 
Add arguments C:\Scripts\script.ps1, and  also I add -f before path.

But when I run this script he don't generate the error file with data.
I thing something is wrong with shedule parameters.

Comment: Hi! Can you please include your postgres script or details that might help your question get answered?
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: I add screen with script.

Comment: Please don't add your script as a screenshot. Paste the actual text into your question. A screenshot is useless for Google and hard to read.

Comment: I change my post and add code.

Comment: Few Observations: Do you have the permission to schedule a script ps script. Check that.Make it with highest privilege option. What is the error you are getting when running from ISE. What is the postgresql script? 
Check the PS execution policy also. First run it normally from ISE , if its working then schedule it.

Comment: We have database on PostgreSQl. 1. Permission ok. 2.Highest privilege set. 3. When I execute script manualy it's ok - file with errors is generate. 4. When I add to schedule no errors, in history - task complet.

Comment: Add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` in the beginning of the Arguments box of your Scheduled Task.

Comment: I added this parameter before sitll when I execute script over schedule, generate empty file.